# Improving weak convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Assume you know $X_n\Rightarrow X$ in a (nice, e.g. Polish) space $(E,d)$, that is $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]\to\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ for all $f\in\mathcal{C}(E,\mathbb{R})$. Now the topology on $E$ determines which functions are actually continuous, thus it determines the "size" of your class of test functions.

Now imagine the following: You equip $E$ with a stronger topology, which is metrized by $d_s$. The original topology is metriced by the weaker metric $d=d_w$. Moreover, you know that $X\in E'\subset E$ a.s. and that for $x\in E'$, you actually have $d_w(x_n,x)\to0$ implies $d_s(x_n,x)$. Can we conclude $X_n\Rightarrow X$ in the stronger topology? I.e. can we improve the weak convergence, given some information on the limiting function $X$?